# How to make distance between two pandas subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two subplots, but the title of lower suplot `Min Price` covered the xlabel of the upper subplot. So, how can I make a distance between the two pandas subplots?

```
mx = df.groupby(['region']).max()['price'].rename(u'Max Price')
mn = df.groupby(['region']).min()['price'].rename(u'Min Price')
df_2 = pd.concat([mx, mn], axis=1)
df_2.index.name = ''
df_2.plot(kind='bar',subplots=True,legend=False,sharex=False,figsize=(10,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like - `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5,  wspace=0.5)` and tweak the args according to your purpose.

Comment: @NickilMaveli TKS...

Comment: Good suggestion by Nickil, you can also try `plt.tight_layout()` for something automatic, that in turn will not let you customize it